# What should be the approach for archiving selected data in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, archive, database-administration

In my current application, I'm using Postgres database for storing all the data for the application.

The application stores various projects and related data like users, preferences, images, resumes etc. For each project, there are entries in multiple tables and the application stores data for multiple Projects.
Once a certain project reaches its shelf life I need to close the project and archive its data to **some place**. Some suggestions I got are

1. Another Database schema with same table structure.
2. Disk
3. HDD
4. files and then zip the file and store in HDD

can anyone suggest on what should be the approach?
PS: I just need to archive data for a chosen project and not backup entire schema.